# PHP if x then image, else other image (so close)

Tags: php

It's a basic question, but I've googled all sorts of variations of it & nothing that quite answers me.  I want to display one of two images.  One if the criteria is met & one if it is not met.  This code works.  If criteria is met, it does display the image.  But there is no alternative

```
<? if(stripslashes($getfeedbackQryRow['CompanyID'])=='344'){?><img src='img1.png' alt='Todays Bite'><? }?>
```

Then I put this together, but it's still wrong

```
<?PHP
if ($getfeedbackQryRow['CompanyID']) == '344') {
    print ("<IMG SRC =/img1.png>");
    }
else {
    print ("<IMG SRC =img2.png>");
    }
?>
```

This one looks like it should be right, but it throws an error...  It's probably a syntax issue.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, an `else` will work here. What error do you get (and more importantly: have you researched it)?

Comment: For future reference, posting said error would be a good addition to the question

Comment: `<IMG SRC =img2.png>` – that is an absolutely _terrible_ way of writing HTML. Please get used to writing it like this, `<img src="img2.png">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra ")"

```
if ($getfeedbackQryRow['CompanyID']) == '344') {
```

Remove the ")" here `['CompanyID'])`

Comment: Thanks!  That was the problem, I took it out & it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($getfeedbackQryRow['CompanyID']) == '344') {
                                // ^------- this is causing your error
```

You should do something simple like this:

```
$image_name = $getfeedbackQryRow['CompanyId'] == '344' ? 'img1.png' : 'img2.png';
echo '<img src="' . $image_name . '">';
```